# Gap between Continuous Functions on Closed and Open subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Let $A$ be a proper non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  If $A$ is closed then Tietze's extension theorem shows that $C(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$ can be identified with $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$.  However, if $A$ is open, this is not so in general.

For example, if $A=(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ then there the function $f= I_{(0,1)} + 2I_{(0,2)}$ is in $C(A,\mathbb{R})$ but cannot be extended to a function in $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.  Conversely however, every function in the later space restricts to one from the former.

---

My question is, if $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n$ where, $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, then is every function in $C(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$ of the form
$$
f = \sum_n f_n I_{A_n}
,
$$
where $f_n$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: What is the domain of definition of each $f_n$ is it $A$ or $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Can be identified with? They're not homeomorphic, if that's what you think... There *is* a linear 1-1 map between them.

Comment: @Sumanta  Their domain in $R^n$ but they are only continuous on $A_n$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh they aren't so the restriction is just an injective linear map but not an extension since it doesn't have a unique section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $A$ is closed then Tietze's extension theorem shows that $C(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$ can be identified with $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$.

Not really. The theorem states that $C(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$ can be identified with a subset of $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$. Or more precisely that there is a function $F:C(A,\mathbb{R}^m)\to C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ with the property $F(f)_{|A}=f$. In particular $F$ is injective. But such bijective function cannot exist if $A$ is a proper closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, since every continuous function $A\to\mathbb{R}^m$ admits multiple (infinitely many) distinct extensions to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> My question is, if $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n$ where, $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, then is every function in $C(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$ of the form
> $$
> f = \sum_n f_n I_{A_n}
> ,
> $$
> where $f_n$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^d$?

This already fails for $N=1$, e.g. $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=1/x$. And so this fails for any $N$ (even infinite) simply by taking $N$ open distinct subsets of $(0,\infty)$ with $0$ being a limit point of one of them.

Comment: Right, so the correct second statement should be for every compact $K\subseteq A$, there exists $f_1,\dots,f_n$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $f|_K = \sum_{n} f_nI_{A_n\cap K}$?  (This would also reflect the ucc topology typically on this set).

Comment: If $K\subseteq A$ is compact then it is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (regardless of what $A$ is) and so Tietze extension theorem applies. And so yes, actually a single $f_1=\cdots = f_n$ exists with this property.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking, if I replace $C(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$ with $C_b(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$ then the second claim would in fact hold no?  Since it seems only explosions at the boundary can cause a problem.

Comment: $C_b(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$ meaning bounded? Still no, e.g. $x\mapsto \sin(1/x)$ cannot be continuously extended to $0$. The problem is not boundary. The problem is [essential discontinuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Essential_discontinuity).

Comment: Right, so its would only be possible if we use $C_0(A,\mathbb{R}^m)$...so that terms vanish at $\partial A$?

Comment: Yes, this will work in that scenario. Because this clearly means that such a map $A\to\mathbb{R}^m$ can be extended to $\overline{A}$ by putting $0$ at the boundary $\partial A$. And then Tietze applies to $\overline{A}$. We again end up with a single $f_1=\cdots =f_n$ function.